# Qt - Realizar uma ação quando um dialogo estiver carregado

Tags: c++, qt

Tenho uma aplicação que serve para fazer o gerenciamento de um quartel da minha cidade, na tela de cadastro de atirador eu gostaria de verificar antes se existe uma turma cadastrada no banco de dados, se não encerrar o dialogo, eu tentei fazer desta maneira:

```
void CadastrarAtirador::showEvent(QShowEvent *ev)
{
    QDialog::showEvent(ev);
    if(turma->anos().isEmpty()){
        this->close();
    }
}
```

A mensagem de erro para o usuário é mostrada normalmente, porém logo em seguida é mostrado um dialogo em branco e quando é fechado o programa lança um assert:

```
Falha ao recuperar os anos:  QSqlError("42P01", "QPSQL: Unable to create query", "ERROR:  relation \"sch_tg.va_turma\" does not exist\nLINE 1: SELECT ano FROM sch_tg.va_turma\n                        ^\n(42P01)")
Falha ao recuperar os anos:  QSqlError("42P01", "QPSQL: Unable to create query", "ERROR:  relation \"sch_tg.va_turma\" does not exist\nLINE 1: SELECT ano FROM sch_tg.va_turma\n                        ^\n(42P01)")
ASSERT: "platformWindow" in file qwindowscontext.cpp, line 1149
09:40:19: The program has unexpectedly finished.
09:40:19: The process was ended forcefully.
```

Comment: Pelo visto é um erro na consulta que você está fazendo para verificar se existe uma turma cadastrada. Verifique se "sch_tg.va_turma" é uma tabela do seu banco.

Comment: @J.PedroA. Isso é obvio, o usuário precisa primeiro criar uma turma, o método anos() serve para executar um select, e se não houver nada ele não preenche o QStringList, então esta vazio, logo se estiver vazio (ou seja não existe esta tabela ainda) ele mostra um erro durante o construtor, e quanto terminar de carregar o dialogo, se não tiver nada no banco ele deve fechar o dialogo, ao menos deveria funcionar assim.